# URL generation error in redirects with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Since Ive installed `devise` I keep getting an `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Devise::Registrations#new`error because of no route matches. The error is in line #20 in my application.html

From around line 20:

```
12        <header class="navbar navbar-default" role= "navigation">
13              <div class="navbar-inner">
14              <div class="container">
15              <div id="logo" class= "navbar-brand"> 
 <%=link_to"home",root_path  %></div>
16              <nav class+"collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
17                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right"> 
18        
19                  <li><%= link_to"submit a new tape", new_post_path %></li>
20                  <li><%= link_to"about", {:controller => 'static_pages', :action => 'about'} %></li>
21
```

routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
devise_for :users  
  get 'static_pages/home'
  get 'static_pages/about'
  resources :posts do
    member do 
      put "like" , to: "posts#upvote"
      put "dislike" , to: "posts#downvote"
    end
  end


  root 'posts#index'
```

end

Comment: Please update with your routes file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody who may be having a similar issue here is what I did to fix it. For some reason line 20 in my application.html (see above post) was causing an issue with `devise` After changing it to this the issue went away:

```
<li><%= link_to"about", about_path %></li>
```

Simple fix!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's no pertinent controller action for your Registrations#New action. I would suggest explicitly setting your controller in your `routes.rb` file, by appending the appropriate options on to your route declaration.

[Here's a link to the proper Devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers)

Also, make sure you're properly routing your static pages. I'm assuming you're wanting your static_pages routes to look something more like:

```
get 'home', to: 'static_pages#index'
...
```